# Is every metric space T1?

Tags: general-topology

I just wanted someone to check if my reasoning is all right. I had two approaches to it.

1.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, take any two points $x$ and $y$ in $X$ let $d(x,y)=4\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$ then balls $B(x,\epsilon)$ and $B(y,\epsilon)$ do the job.

So it seems all right, but I don't know why feel like there is something wrong

2.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and $x\in X$. Take a sequence $x_n=x$, then $x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$ so $\{x\}\subset X$ contains all its limit points so every singleton in $(X,d)$ is closed set. So $(X,d)$ is $T1$.

And here I know what creates my doubts, I think I saw that some people define a limit point as a limit of a sequence that is non-constant, or in terms of balls they want every ball to contain other point than its center (here $x$).

So is it all right?

Comment: I don't see a problem with 1. Every metric space is not just $T_1$, but even normal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space). The hierarchy is like $T_1 \subset $ Hausdroff $\subset$ normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue with your first approach is one of semantics. It seems that $\epsilon$ is arbitrary--based on "let...for some $\epsilon$"--so that $4\epsilon$ would also be arbitrary, but since $x$ and $y$ had already been chosen, then $d(x,y)$ would be fixed, so there's no way to justify that $d(x,y)=4\epsilon.$ Instead, you should *choose* $\epsilon$ in terms of $d(x,y).$ It seems that you wanted to say something like "Let $\epsilon=\frac14d(x,y).$" At that point, you can (and should) show that $y\notin B(x,\epsilon)$ and $x\notin B(y,\epsilon).$ Ultimately, you only need to show one of these, as a similar proof will work for the other.

[P.S.: There's no need for $\epsilon$ to be that small. Can you find the greatest $\epsilon$ that will do the job?]

---

Your second approach doesn't work, as you suspected. You haven't shown that $\{x\}$ is closed (nor even *sequentially* closed, which may be different). Instead, you'd need to show that if $y\in X$ with $y\neq x,$ then $x_n\not\to y.$

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions about how you'd fix the second proof, or finish fixing the first. Also, if you want to bounce a proof attempt off me, feel free to make edits to your question and let me know.

Comment: When it comes to 1st i got What you mean but when i say for any x and y i can choose epsilon such that $d(x,y)=4\epsilon$ I think it is all right as well i could  write $d(x,y)=4\epsilon(x,y)$ and i know that I don't need epsilon so small i think even $d(x,y)=\epsilon$ Would do the job then one point would be in the boundary of epsilon bal of enother so not in the open ball so it is all right. Thanks for your help!